# Defining jquery variable into function that's out of scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, variables, scope

I'm trying to pass a paramater (gmap_settings) to a function (initialize) that is in an included external js file. My php file looks something like this:

```
<?php
$setting = array(
    'zoom' => 8
);

$json = json_encode($setting);
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    var gmap_settings = $.parseJSON ('<?php echo $json; ?>');
--> google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', $(document).initialize(gmap_settings));
});

//]]>
</script>
```

For simplicity's sake, lets say that the external js file looks like this:

```
(function($) {
    var initialize = function( data ) { alert(data); };
})( jQuery );
```

Regardless of what I try I can't figure out how to pass gmap_settings into `initialize()`. I've tried function `initialize()` in the external file:

```
$(document).initialize.gmap_settings
$(document).initialize({gmap_settings})
initialize(gmap_settings)
```

I don't understand what I'm missing.

Comment: No. The `var initialize` is a *local* variable. That means you *cannot* access it from outside.

Comment: Instead of trying to parse a non-escaped echoed JSON string just use `var gmap_settings = <?php echo $json; ?>;`

Comment: `$(document).initialize` seems like you're trying to [write a plugin](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring)

Comment: I was trying to avoid writing a plugin. I've written them before but thought I could get away with just calling a function for this application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

why would you think that `$(document).initialize` would work?

You could implement the module pattern in your external javascript file and return an object and call initialize on that object

```
var YourModule = (function($) {
    return {
       initialize: function( data ) { alert(data)} 
    };
})( jQuery );
```

now you have a variable you can use

```
var newModule = Object.create(YourModule);
newModule.initialize('This will be alerted')
```

Comment: This worked. Is this the same format that a plugin would be written in minus the $.fn (prototype)? The idea of prototypes is lost on me despite the fact that I can get it to work at the lowest level of comprehension.

Comment: @brandonhowlett idk javascript is still brand new to me.  It seems like you are interested in a jquery plugin based on `$.fn.`.  There are many blog posts on the best ways to write a jquery plugin

Comment: About a decade ago I was a PHP developer, and now I find myself frankensteining pieces of jquery together for a personal project, it's funny. Thanks for the help!